# how to use -webkit-transform: translateX using % and position absolute

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

Hi guys a while back i posted a question regarding a banner i was making, well i have the animation working now but i cant get `-webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)` to work when i combine it with `position:absolute`.

The problem is i have 3 images and 3 bits of text that i need to fly onto the screen one after the other and end up overlapping which is why i was trying to use `position:absolute` but i cant get `-webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)` to work when i do this however i can get `-webkit-transform:   translateX(-40px)` to work but that doesn't help me as i want it to be the same on different screen sizes. Does anybody know how i can get my animation to work with `-webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)` and have multiple images overlapping?

Example Code:

Html:

```
        <div class="text3" id="txt3">
            Moving Text
        </div>
```

Css:

```
#txt3{
position:absolute;
top: 150px;
z-index: 1;
}
.text3 {
-webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-duration: 15s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-duration: 15s;
-o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-duration: 15s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-fill-mode: both;} 


@-webkit-keyframes text3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)
            ;opacity: 1;
    }
    3% {
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(20%)
    }
    37% {
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(20%)
            ;opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(35%)
            ;opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
            opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:   translateX(35%)
    }
}
    @-moz-keyframes text3 {
        0% {
            -moz-transform:   translateX(-40%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        3% {
            -moz-transform:   translateX(-40%)
        }
        30% {
            -moz-transform:   translateX(20%)
        }
        37% {
            -moz-transform:   translateX(20%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            -moz-transform:   translateX(35%)
                ;opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 0;
            -moz-transform:   translateX(35%)
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes text3 {
        0% {
            -o-transform:   translateX(-40%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        3% {
            -o-transform:   translateX(-40%)
        }
        30% {
            -o-transform:   translateX(20%)
        }
        37% {
            -o-transform:   translateX(20%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            -o-transform:   translateX(35%)
                ;opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 0;
            -o-transform:   translateX(35%)
        }
    }
    @keyframes text3 {
        0% {
            transform:   translateX(-40%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        3% {
            transform:   translateX(-40%)
        }
        30% {
            transform:   translateX(20%)
        }
        37% {
            transform:   translateX(20%)
                ;opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            transform:   translateX(35%)
                ;opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 0;
            transform:   translateX(35%)
        }
    }
.text3 {
    -webkit-animation-name: text3;
    -moz-animation-name: text3;
    -o-animation-name: text3;
    animation-name: text3;
}
```

Here are some working example of the animation:

[-webkit-transform:   translateX(-40%)](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DTL/)

[position:absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/dd9hD/)

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

crackruckles

Comment: What browser are you using? This is not working for me even when i remove position absolute.

Comment: `transform:translateX(-40%)` relates to the elements **own** dimensions. You should be using **position values** to move the div offscreen and the animate it into place.

Comment: The problem with that is i want them to overlap which is why i was using position absolute and z-indexes and the browser is chrome 36.0.1985.125m